# Checking for installed package for bash

Tags: linux, bash, package

I need a script that will check whether packages are installed for `apache2`, `mysql` and `php`.

Example output:

```
apache2 .... ok
mysql .... ok
php ... not installed
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Please state your particular distribution of interest, and what are you intending to do. Are you trying to run something or just creating some kind of installer which will tell user that he misses some dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages are not necessarily named the same on different distributions, and querying for their presence depends on the package manager in use.

Debian (dpkg):

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${Package}\n' apache2 mysql-server php5 2>/dev/null
```

Fedora (RPM):

```
rpm -q --qf '%{NAME}\n' httpd mysql-server php 2>/dev/null
```

Gentoo (Portage):

```
equery --quiet list www-servers/apache:2 dev-lang/php dev-db/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming APT:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i apache2
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS (will only show the ones that *are* installed):

```
yum list installed | egrep -i 'apache|mysql|php'
```